# Getting Random "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am randomly getting an:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: x >= y
```

(where x and y are varying values each time exception occurs, for example first time x was 7 and y was 7, next time x was 4 and y was 2).  Following is the method in which I believe the error is occurring.  I say believe because the stack trace does not show any reference to a specific line of code in this method.  However, this method is the only area where vectors are used in the associated class.

```
    private void displayResults(ResultSet rset){

      Vector<Vector<String>> resultRows = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
      Vector<String> resultRow = null;
      int resultCount = 0;

      try{
         resultRows.clear();
         if (rset != null){
          while (rset.next()){
              resultRow = new Vector<String>();
              resultRow.add(rset.getString(1));
              resultRow.add(rset.getString(2));
              resultRow.add(rset.getString(3));
              resultRow.add(rset.getString(4));
              resultRow.add(rset.getString(5));
              resultRow.add(rset.getString(6));
              resultRow.add(rset.getString(7));
              resultRow.add(rset.getString(8));
              resultRow.add(rset.getString(9));

              resultRows.add(resultRow);
              resultCount++;                
          }

          try{
             vax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                  resultsTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(resultRows, colHdrs));
                  resultsTable.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                  resultsTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(950, 480));
                  resultsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(100);
                  resultsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(50);
                  resultsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(50);
                  resultsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(50);
                  resultsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(50);
                  resultsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMaxWidth(50);
                  resultsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMaxWidth(50);
                  resultsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setMaxWidth(100);
                  resultsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setMaxWidth(100);
               }
             )};
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e){

          }
          catch (InvocationTargetException e){

          }

          .... Code to display results ...

         }
      }
      catch (Exception e){
        Sysyem.err.println("Exception encountered processing a result");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
```

First part of provided stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4>= 2
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:447)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
```

Notes:

1. resultsTable is a JTable
2. As mentioned above exception does not happen every time this method executes
3. Exception does not appear to prevent all results from displaying correctly
   based on a visual inspection

Comment: _Sometimes?_ Verify that Swing GUI objects are constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It looks like you have some try-catch statements there that could help narrow it down. Which `System.err` message prints when the exception occurs? If it is the first message, it probably has something to do with the `getColumn` method. If it's the second error message, you'll want to look at the `getString` method.

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't throw an exception every time, since you're calling rset.get(0), and column indices in a ResultSet start at 1.

Comment: First of all I apologize I provided the incorrect starting index for the rset.getString() method calls.  This code exists on a classified server from which I can not electronically copy/move to an unclassified server.  I have to type it in by hand and I actually use constants attributes defined in another file for which I did not include to minimize the amount of code provided.  The index range is from 1 to 9 (nice catch JB Nizel).  To answer question by Kunruh, none of my System.err.println messages within exception catch blocks are printed.  I basically put them in for debug.

Comment: Fixed issue based on recommendation from trashgod (MUCH APPRECIATED).  See updated code using javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() invocation and associated catch blocks.

Comment: This tends to happen when you modify the state of the model outside of the EDT, which causes a race condition